# Unit test for Webservice using OCMock and XCT framework

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I am very new to unit testing in iOS and would like to write one unit test that can cover the `GET` method. Pasting the code below

```
+ (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                        success:(OHTTPServiceSuccessCallback)success
                        failure:(OHTTPServiceFailureCallback)failure {
    return [[RSurveyService sharedInstance].manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [RSurveyService sharedInstance].baseURL, URLString]
                                             parameters:parameters
                                                success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                    if (success) success(operation, responseObject);
                                                }
                                                failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (failure) failure(operation, error);
                                                }
            ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an XCTest file and import   XCTest/XCTest.h

The unit tests start with the word test and use asserts. The tests need their own separate target if you don't already have one, you can make one.

```
- (void)testSomething {
    // Setup test objects objA and objB

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(objA, objB, @"");
    // Add more XCTAsserts as desired
}
```

That's pretty much it.